# CGIとして実行するとImportErrorで動かないPythonスクリプト

Tags: python, centos, apache

python初心者なので、見当違いの事を言ってましたら、ご指摘ください。
ここ一週間、ずっと悩んでまして、どなたかヒントだけでも頂けると助かります。

現在の環境

```
# /usr/bin/python -V
Python 3.5.1

# /usr/local/pyenv/shims/pip3 list
pip (8.1.1)
PyMySQL (0.7.2)
setuptools (18.2)
```

作ったプログラム

```
test2.py

#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymysql.cursors
```

を

```
/usr/bin/python test2.py
```

とすると、エラーは起こらないのですが、

Apache経由のブラウザからアクセスすると、Internal Server Errorとなってしまい、
Apacheのエラーログに以下が出力されます。

```
  File "/var/www/python.hogehoge.com/public_html/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pymysql.cursors
ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'
Premature end of script headers: test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://python.hogehoge.com/test2.py
  File "/var/www/python.hogehoge.com/public_html/test2.py", line 3, in <module>, referer: http://python.hogehoge.com/test2.py
    import pymysql.cursors, referer: http://python.hogehoge.com/test2.py
ImportError: No module named 'pymysql', referer: http://python.hogehoge.com/test2.py
Premature end of script headers: test2.py, referer: http://python.hogehoge.com/test2.py
```

※上記は日付等のエラーログのヘッダー部分は消してあります。
　全て、[Thu Apr 07 19:53:54 2016] [error] [client 111.111.11.11]が先頭についています。

サーバー環境はさくらインターネットのVPSで、Apacheはvirtualhostをいくつか切っていて、その一つに置いています。
お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

2016/04/08 02:29 追記

apacheの設定で、

```
<Directory "/var/www/＊＊＊＊＊＊＊/public_html/">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

として、CGIとして動かしているという事を言いたかったのです。＞Apache経由

```
# which httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
# ps auxw | grep /usr/sbin/httpd
root     20000  0.0  0.0 100004   912 pts/1    S+   02:23   0:00 grep /usr/sbin/httpd
```

apacheはrootで動かしてます。

Comment: pyenv で複数の環境を作っていませんか？ `pyenv versions`で確認してみて下さい。pythonの動作確認はrootユーザーで行なっているようですが、apachを動かすユーザ権限でも同じpyenv の環境が設定されていますか？

Comment: そういえば「Apache経由」とはどういう環境なのでしょうか。mod-wsgiとかっていう物なのでしょうか。

Comment: mjyさん、早速ありがとうございます。
色々やっていてpython3を複数インストールしてしまっていました。

具体的には、wgetで取ってきたものと、pyenvで入れたものが二つ存在してしまっていたので、pyenvの方をアンインストールして、/usr/bin/に残したpython本体へのシンボリックリンクを張る事で、動作しました。

Comment: 自己解決したのであればコメントで返信するのではなく、その内容を自分で「回答」として投稿して承認(チェックマークを入れる）してください

Comment: 投稿ルールが分かっておらず、失礼しました。回答としても同じ内容を投稿しましたが、承認チェックマークの方法が分からなかったので、やっておりません。方法を教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 回答の左側にあるグレーのチェックマークをクリックするのですが、自己回答を承認するには質問から48時間経たないといけないので、もう数時間待つ必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ある実行方法では動くのに、別の実行方法では動かない場合はそもそも実行されているPythonが異なっている事があります。
対象のスクリプトに自身を実行しているPythonについての情報を出力させるには例えば以下のようにします。

```
import sys, os
print("sys.executable: ", sys.executable)
print("executable_link: ", os.readlink(sys.executable))
print("sys.path: ", sys.path)
print("sys.version_info: ", sys.version_info)
print("sys.api_version: ", sys.api_version)

import sysconfig
for p in sysconfig.get_path_names():
    print("sysconfig:path:" + p + ": " + sysconfig.get_path(p))
```

同じPythonで実行されていても、モジュールの検索パスが異なっている事もあります。
質問者の例だと`import`に失敗しているので、`sys.path`が異なっているのではないでしょうか。

`import`は成功しても、意図していないモジュールが読み込まれている事もあります。
その場合、moduleオブジェクトの`__path__`や`__file__`でいったいどこから読み込まれているのか調べます。

```
# PILモジュールの例
# ビルトインのモジュールは __path__ や __file__ を持っていません
import PIL
print(PIL.__path__, PIL.__file__, PIL.__package__, PIL.__loader__)
```

Comment: 「別の実行方法では動かない場合はそもそも実行されているPythonが異なっている」まさに、コレでした。
最初Python2.6（さくらVPSに最初から入っていたもの）でエラーになっていたので、Pythonのバージョン違いだろうとして、設定を変えたつもりだったのですが、まさかPython3を二つ（自分でですが）入れてしまっていたとは、全く気づきませんでした。
ご指摘、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

色々やっていてpython3を複数インストールしてしまっていました。
具体的には、wgetで取ってきたものと、pyenvで入れたものが二つ存在してしまっていたので、pyenvの方をアンインストールして、/usr/bin/に残したp‌​ython本体へのシンボリックリンクを張る事で、動作しました。

```
ln -s /usr/local/python/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```