# GCPのVMインスタンス上でImportError: No module named 'pandas' エラーが発生します

Tags: python3, pandas, google-cloud

▼前提
GCP上のVMインスタンスにPython3.6の環境を構築し、pip3でpandas,numpy,sklearnなどのモジュールをインストールしました。

▼事象
しかし、`import pandas` を実行すると、

```
[Tue Dec 24 09:09:11.447228 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 19982] [client 34.84.154.183:35282] AH01215:     import pandas as pd:deploy_model_bmw.py
[Tue Dec 24 09:09:11.447256 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 19982] [client 34.84.154.183:35282] AH01215: ImportError: No module named 'pandas':deploy_model_bmw.py
```

とエラーになってしまいます。
なにか解決策をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けると助かります。

▼その他
他のpandasのバージョンも試しましたが同様のエラーが発生しました。

pandas 以外のnumpyなどのモジュールは問題なく読み込めます。

```
pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.25.3
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/g3atom1take1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, numpy, pytz
Required-by: mlxtend
```

Comment: 参考: [CGIとして実行するとImportErrorで動かないPythonスクリプト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/23837/16894)

Comment: `pyenv versions`の結果って何になりますか？

Comment: `3.6.0` となります。